# Best CSS Layout for typical ecommerce sites

Tags: css, e-commerce

Ok, I am probably going to get very varied opinions on this question but here goes anyway: what would be the best css layout type for a typical ecommerce site. Typical as in standard grid based product pages, header footer etc.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish with this layout? Currently this question is very subjective, so its hard to say "This is the best layout. Period." If you give us a very precise list of your requirements and change this to a question about ease of use of different designs, you'll probably have more success. :D

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'standard grid based product pages" and headers/footers? Could you post a link, picture or image or what you are trying to illustrate?

Answer (score 1):

An infinite number of layouts will get the job done, and its impossible to definitively say which one is 'best'. however, there are a few guidelines that should help:

- Make the product look good.If you're going to sell something, you need to make it quickly apparent why your product is awesome. Some prominent images can help this greatly.
- Don't make things more complicated than they need to be. Be minimalistic! No one's going to say "Well, the site design is very complex and intricate, so I should probably give them my money..."
- Make it easy on the eyes and the mind. Consider usability: people should be able to find what they need quickly and efficiently. The longer people have to spend on your site before being able to buy something, the less successful the site will be. Also, [make sure you're using colors that aren't too stressful on the eyes](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/find-the-perfect-colors-for-your-website/).

When in doubt, look at [other successful E-commerce sites.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/22/35-beautiful-and-effective-ecommerce-websites/) You often don't need to spend countless hours thinking of a new site layout when there are plenty of tried and true designs out there. :D